# Struts2 JQuery Grid: Missing tooltips on header

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-jquery-grid

So I've taken over an old project with Struts2 (2.3.32) with struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.1. There is a grid that is working well. Only problem, is that the table header is missing the tooltips. They are important, since the columns are narrow and have abbreviated titles. I've never worked with jquery grid, so i've no clue where to start.

I've tried with the tooltip and label attributes (see the "test" string) and with javascript (the TODO came from the former dev, but doesn't work either). Interestingly it shows the tooltips for all the other cells on hover, displaying the value in the cell. I'd expect to at least do the same for the header, but it doesn't.

```
<sjg:grid
    id="gridedittable"
    loadonce="false"
    caption="Werbemittel Schnellerfassung" 
    dataType="json" 
    href="%{remoteurl}" 
    footerrow="true"
    pager="true" 
    navigator="true"
    navigatorSearchOptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"
    navigatorAddOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
    navigatorEditOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}"
    navigatorEdit="false"
    navigatorView="false"
    navigatorDelete="false"
    navigatorAdd="false"
    navigatorSearch="false"
    navigatorDeleteOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="20,30,50,100"
    rowNum="20"
    editurl="%{editurl}"
    editinline="true"
    onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
    viewrecords="true"
    height="450">

...

    <s:iterator value="#ads.values()" var="ads" status="adStatus">
        <sjg:gridColumn name="advertisingMap.%{#ads.itemId}" index="%{shortName}" title="%{shortName}" width="50" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false" search="false" tooltip="test" label="test"/> <!-- TODO: Add tooltip onmouseover="javascript:tooltip.show('test');" onmouseout="javascript:tooltip.hide();" -->
    </s:iterator>
</sjg:grid>
```

Comment: There's no code is posted for showing attempts to make a tooltips on subcomponents of the grid. This question should include more details and clarify the problem. The [mcve] is required for wide screening the diagnose of the problem.

Comment: @RomanC i don't understand. There is a tooltip and a label attribute, both to no effect. What else is needed for the tooltips? Can you point me to anything, i really can't find much about grid subcomponents and tooltips?

Comment: No, it doesn't work this way. There's no tooltips and lebels in subcomponents of the grid. You won't find any useful information about it unless you do it yourself.

Comment: @RomanC As i've said, i've no experience with this. So how would i do it by myself? Also why or better how does it work on the cells, except the header row?

Comment: If you don't have experience with this then you can't. The cells are different things. You have not posted js code. Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted. Learn more about comments…

Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more about formatting…